# Mergin cvs files with primary keys in Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have two big cvs files around 60,000 rows in each and these have primary keys both the files have the same primary keys but different data related to the primary keys, i need to merge these files.

Is there a way to complete the task with Excel?

Comment: There are many ways, formulas like Vlookup or INDEX/MATCH, Using vba, or Power queries, or a combination of all three.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be the following [`CMD` comand](http://analystcave.com/merge-csv-files-or-txt-files-in-a-folder/): `copy *.csv merge.csv` Afterwards you can use `remove duplicates` on the resulting table. If you have Office 2013+ and need to do that frequently then you can also use PowerQueries (especially designed for that).

Comment: @ScottCraner, Do you know of any documentation i can look at to use one of the services you mentioed to merge the files?